# NullPointerException while opening database through a fragment

Tags: android, database, android-listfragment

I am trying to populate the ListFragment from one of the columns in my Database.
For that i am trying to use

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        db.open();
        db = new NotesDatabase(getActivity());
        c = db.getAllRows();

    getActivity().startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] fromField = new String[] { NotesDatabase.KEY_TITLE };
    int[] toView = new int[] { R.id.item_title };
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.list_item, c, fromField, toView, 0);
    setListAdapter(myCAdapter);
}
```

but i dont know why i am getting a NullPointerException on db.open(); and c = db.getAllRows();

```
db.open()
    public NotesDatabase open() {
    db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
    }
```

db.getAllRows();

```
    public Cursor getAllRows() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null,
            null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
    }
```

DBHelper

```
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

or if there is a better a better way to populate the list view of fragment from a database?
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Where are you instantiating a new instance of SQLiteDatabase db in the fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        db.open();
        db = new NotesDatabase(getActivity());
        c = db.getAllRows();
```

1. Open the database
2. Create the database
3. Get all the rows.

Logically speaking. create it first. then open. then get all the rows. So swithc line 1 and lone 2.

Another thing is that , I assume your getting NPE at myDBHelper, because you never created that helper.

Comment: omg...it was such a idiotic mistake :(.... thanks a lot...
btw..is this way of populating the ListFragment Fine?

Comment: If it works, its fine. If you ask , is it a good approach, it doesnt fit here at SO, and we need to know your full project.

Comment: kk...i will try out this method as it is working now... thank you

Answer (score 1):

aren't you doing it reverse?

```
db.open();
db = new NotesDatabase(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just initialise your databasehelper before opening it:
db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the db.open before the new so it doesn't exist yet, you are trying to open a null db.